# How to restart Heroku app from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm going on vacation for a week without my development laptop, and I'd like to be able to reset my Heroku app if needed.  I don't have background jobs set up and I'd rather not set them up just for this.

I'm thinking I might just scale the dynos down and then back up, but not sure if there are other options.  Is there a way to run the equivalent of `heroku restart` from the browser?

Comment: Do you have an iphone?

Comment: No, probably will be using an android tablet or phone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Android you can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cyberstride&hl=en

If you have an Iphone you can use https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/nezumi-for-heroku/id346715875?mt=8 or https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/iroku-for-heroku/id667837229?mt=8

Comment: Cool. This is more than I need, but for 10 bucks I like all the options.